# In mysql, are DATE_ADD() and simply +/- INVERVAL different?

Tags: mysql, date, dateadd, dateinterval

I am doing a leetcode question (https://leetcode.com/problems/new-users-daily-count/), I get the correct answer by using date_add(), but wrong answer using -/+ interval. I thought I can use them interactively, but now seems I need to always use date_add()?

```
select date_add('2019-06-30', interval -90 day), cast("2019-06-30" as date) - interval 3 month
```

output:

```
{"headers": ["date_add('2019-06-30', interval -90 day)", "cast(\"2019-06-30\" as date) - interval 3 month"], "values": [["2019-04-01", "2019-03-30"]]}
```

I got "2019-04-01" using date_add but "2019-03-30" using - interval.

Comment: If you execute EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query] followed by SHOW WARNINGS, you can see exactly how different the two queries are

Comment: NOTE that `interval -90 day` is NOT the same as `interval -3 month`  The difference you observe is due to that difference.  It's not due to using  `+ INTERVAL` vs `DATE_ADD`.

Comment: AHHHH thank you for pointing out my dumb mistake!!! @spencer7593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting 3 months is almost always going to give a different result than adding -90 days, because 3 months is not usually 90 days.  If you change your date_add form from

```
date_add('2019-06-30', interval -90 day)
```

to

```
date_add('2019-06-30', interval -3 months)
```

or change your +/- interval form from

```
cast("2019-06-30" as date) - interval 3 month
```

to

```
cast("2019-06-30" as date) - interval 90 day
```

they should match.